# Single file in a working copy (branch) pointing to trunk under TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Got a very strange problem.

I've got a working copy which is from a branch. When I commit any changes from this working copy, one single file in the working copy gets committed to the trunk.

If I right-click this single file and click Commit the SVN URL displayed points to the /trunk and not the branch.

How on earth could this happen? I used TortoiseSVN to create the branch in the first place.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by using the SVN switch command on the single file and correctly point it to the branch.

Not sure why this happened, it seems when TortoiseSVN created the branch and switched the working copy it did not switch this one single file.

Answer (score 3):

With Tortoise, creating a branch does not switch your working copy to it - it will remain on the trunk. To switch the working copy, use Switch... from the Tortoise context menu, or check out the branch as a different working copy.

Comment: When I created the branch it asked me whether I wanted to switch the working copy to the new branch. It seems it did not switch over all the files!